# On sums over non-symmetric sets

Tags: combinatorics, summation, symmetry

**Definition:** We say that a subset $A\subset \mathbb{N}_0\times \mathbb{N}_0$ is symmetric if it satisfies the property: $(a,b)\in A \Rightarrow (b,a)\in A.$ We say that the subset $A$ is non-symmetric if it does not satisfies the property.

My question is the following

**Question:**
Let $p\in (0,\frac{1}{2}).$ Is there any non-symmetric subset $A\subset \mathbb{N}_0\times \mathbb{N}_0$ such that 
$$\sum_{(a,b)\in A} p^a (1-p)^b=\sum_{(a,b)\in A} p^b (1-p)^a \mbox{ ?}$$

Comment: Well, in the case that $p=0.5,$ the set $A=\bigl\{(0,1)\bigr\}$ works. Other such sets will work on a case-by-case basis dependent on $p.$ Do you want one that works for *all* $p$? Do you want a way to determine which (if any) $A$ will work for some given, arbitrary $p$?

Comment: Yes, of course, moreover, if $ p=0.5 $ the sums always coincide.

Comment: Interesting question, taking $p=\frac{1}{n}$ already gives rise to interesting number theory. My guess is no there is no solution if $A$ is finite.

Comment: Thanks! I agree, I believe there is not such A finite, but I do not know how to prove it :(